# SQLConnection instances dispose via Dapper

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, sqlconnection, dbconnection

I am using [ASP.NET web forms unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity/) for DI in my project:

Next, I have installed [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) in my project to call database resources via my DAL. In my Startup class I have plugged IDbConnection like this so that the Dapper can make use of that IDbConnection everywhere:

```
 container.RegisterInstance<IDbConnection>(new SqlConnection(connectionString));
```

My question here is that if I use the dbconnection like this in my class, how will the sql connection be diposed when the work is done:

```
public class MyProvider: IMyProvider
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
    public MyProvider(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> GetMyData()
    {
        const string sql = @"SELECT * from mytable";

        return await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<Content>(sql);
    }
}
```

I am worried about this part "(new SqlConnection(connectionString))" in my start up while setting up the DI hooks. How and when will the SQLConnection be disposed after calling the database calls. There is no *using* written any where in the above code.

Will Dapper dispose the SQLConnection after making the call? If no, then can you share how to convert the above code to dispose the SQL Connection after making dapper call?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be disposed, because the instance is effectively a Singleton, and is held for the lifetime of the application. This is not the correct way to inject a DB connection.

Instead, you should register a factory method, using `RegisterFactory`

```cs
container.RegisterFactory<IDbConnection>(f => new SqlConnection(connectionString));
```

Then you can use that to get a *new* connection and place it in a `using` block.

Comment: But does it matter that it won't be disposed/be held for life? Disposing is effectively a synonym for closing, and dapper will open and close (not dispose) the connection as part of its operation, leasing and returning some open TCP connection from the pool, so unless there will be some attempt to execute another query while still enumerating the results of a first, I'm not sure it'll make much difference whether a single instance is reused or whether new ones are created..

Comment: @CaiusJard Could be, but wait til someone multi-threads it.... Anyway, just feels wrong, but everyone is entitled to their opinion